# Изменение volatile переменной приложения на С++ из приложения на С#

Tags: c#, c++, volatile

Здравствуйте, товарищи! Суть вопроса такова: в приложении, написанном на С++, имеется такого рода глобальная переменная:

```
volatile int reread = 0;
```

Возможно ли (и как) изменить ее значение из другого приложения, которое было бы написано на С#? Если нет, то аналогичный вопрос, но уже касательно С++. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А за что минус? Честных способов нет, можно извратиться через [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx), если знаете адрес.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо! Уже читаю и подбираю адрес хД

Answer (score 1):

Менять память другого процесса очень плохая идея(например переменная может в момент записи в регистре процессора находиться). Для взаимодействия 2-х процессов хорошо подойдёт `socket`. Если именно под виндовс то для обмена данными между процессами есть:

DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange)

OLE

atom (атомы)

pipes (анонимные каналы)

named pipes (именованные каналы)

почтовые ящики (mailslots)

RPC

сокеты

файлы, проецируемые в память (memory-mapped files)

разделяемая память (Shared Memory)

Comment: `volatile`-переменная по идее не может, она всегда перечитывается. Способы, предлагаемые вами, подразумевают сотрудничество целевого процесса, а у ТС, судя по всему, такого нет.

Comment: Так никто не отменял также кэш и мультипроцессорность. Конечно не должно ничего эдакого быть но гарантий 100% нет. А найти адрес можно тогда через cheatengine

Comment: Ну volatile же. Он гарантирует, что переменная не будет кешироваться.

Comment: @VladD Это вы верно подметили. У меня есть стороннее приложение, исходный код которого мне примерно известен. Так же мне известно, что внутри есть volatile переменная (дабы ее просто в не сожрал компилятор при оптимизации), которая самой программой не меняется. Так что ее изменение не должно влечь за собой чего-то плохого

Comment: Если программа не меняет значение переменной сама то искать её можно до скончания веков даже с cheat engine. WriteProcessMemory как уже было сказано должно помочь.